# How to Insert million of Insert Command having in .sql file

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have .sql file which contains millions of Insert commands, and they are having insert statements to be inserted into different tables. When I am executing by opening in SQL SERVER MANAGEMENT it says

> Insufficient memory to continue the execution of program

Comment: `Insufficient memory to continue the execution of program`. What kind of information do you require instead of this? You need to manually check what's taking up your memory and provide us more information.

Comment: Why do you have a text file with millions of insert commands? Have you considered just exporting the data, instead of insert statements, and using more efficient bulk operations? Or processing your massive script file with something a bit more efficient than SSMS (e.g. SQLCMD, PowerShell, C#)?

Comment: From PO: Hi All thank you for your quick responce when i try to execute sqlcmd -S myServer\instanceName -i C:\myScript.sql  i changed instance name but its throwing error Incorrect syntax near 'S'. can any one help please

Comment: are you running this from the command line?

Comment: please add to your question your attempts, and copy and paste the error message you get.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can save the SQL in a file and execute it from the command line using sqlcmd. For example:

```
sqlcmd -S myServer\instanceName -i C:\myScript.sql
```

Please note: If your instance is a default instance (i.e. the instance name is MSSQLSERVER), then do not specify it as part of the sqlcmd parameters. To connect to the default instance, simply specify the server name. For example:

```
sqlcmd -S myServer -i C:\myScript.sql
```

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest you try running the .sql from the command line (sqlcmd.exe) instead of loading it in SSMS.

[SQLCMD - MSDN Link](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms170572.aspx)